# Java: Is casting to generic type in parent class safe when generic is <T extends Parent>?

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have a parent class for all of my custom exceptions, ParentException. I want all child exceptions to have a method that adds a message to the exception. To do this I created a generic method that returns an object of generic type after adding the message to it. I use `this` in the parent class method to add the message then return `this` but since the method returns the generic type I casted it to the generic type T. This seems to work, but gives a warning. My code is as follows:

```
public class ParentException extends RuntimeException{

    private String message;

    public ParentException() {
        message = "";
    }

    public void addToMessage(String msg) {
        message += msg;
    }

    public void printMessage() {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    public <T extends ParentException> T withMessage(String msg) {
        this.addToMessage(msg);
        return (T) this; // This line gives the warning
    }
}
```

The warning given by that line is `Unchecked cast from ParentException to T`. The method does seem to work as expected, so I'm not worried but I'd like a better understanding of why this gives a warning in the first place.

Will this cast always be safe? Otherwise what case would cause a runtime error?

Comment: No, it is not safe, since `T` can be inferred to be a child of `ParentException` and in that case, the cast will fail (if called on a `ParentException` object). It will only work if `T` is actually `ParentException`.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to use generics here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will compile, but will fail at runtime:

```
class ChildException extends ParentException { }

ParentException p = new ParentException();
ChildException c = p.withMessage("Connection failed");
```

I realize it wouldn’t make much sense to write that, but the point is that the compiler warning about an unsafe cast can prevent this landmine in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. But what if I make the `ParentException` class abstract? That would work for most cases but what about this one?

    `ParentException p = new ChildException();
    ChildException c = p.withMessage("Connection Failed");`

Comment: It works for that case, but what about a concrete child class and concrete grandchild class?  And with some imagination, I think we can come up with a lot of similar scenarios.

Comment: Ok, I can see how this gets dangerous. What would be a good general solution then? I'd rather not have to override the method in all child classes.

Comment: I’m not sure there is a way to write an inheritable covariant method.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this case:

```
class SubException extends ParentException {...}

ParentException ex = new ParentException();
SubException sub = ex.withMessage("blah");
```

The last line will throw a class cast exception, because `ParentException` can not be cast to `SubException`.

---

You could create a static helper method:

```
class ParentException extends RuntimeException{
    ...
    protected static <T extends ParentException> T withMessage(T instance, String msg) {
        instance.addToMessage(msg);
        return instance;
    }

    public ParentException withMessage(String msg) {
        return withMessage(this, msg);
    }
}
```

And use covariant return types to override this method:

```
class SubException extends ParentException {
    @Override
    public SubException withMessage(String msg) {
        return withMessage(this, msg);
    }   
}
```

Then, if you have a `SubException` variable, the call to `withMessage` will return a `SubException` too.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. But what if I make the `ParentException` class abstract? That would work for most cases but what about this one?

    `ParentException p = new ChildException();
    ChildException c = p.withMessage("Connection Failed");`

Comment: @GeoffMcLennan That is just a trick to hide the cast, as it will be inserted by the compiler behind the scenes. That will compile to: `ParentException p = new ChildException(); ChildException c = (ChildException) p.withMessage("Connection Failed");` Which of course is just as safe as a regular cast in that situation.

Comment: It does more than hide the cast,  there is no object instantiation of ParentException type. I just tested the example in my comment and it works without a runtime error. And if ParentException is abstract, that should prevent any errors caused by your initial case, but still leaves room for errors as in @VGR 's comment below.